# Bash script does not recognize commands (Perl and Python scripts)

Tags: bash, scripts, python, perl

I have this script in bash inside which is defined to use perl and python for subprograms that need to analyze my data.

Script is executing fine until Step3 and Step4 and crashes with `command not found`.
I tried `chmod u+x` those .pl .py scripts; I tried to explicitly define path of perl and python, but nothin works. Scripts are in the same directory in which is .sh script I am executing. I'm missing something and I don't know what.

Here is my error error in steps 3 & 4:

[image: error in step3&4]

Here is a bash script and .pl and .py scripts that need to be used in Steps 3 & 4.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
    echo "Please type $0 -h for helps"
    exit 65
fi

FORMAT="fastq"
REF_PATH="/home/maja2004lts/16sPIP/"
MODE="fast"
THREAD=8
Version="0.1.1"
step="step1"
THREAD=8

while getopts ":i:r:f:s:p:m:t:hv" opt
do
    case "${opt}" in
        i) NGS=${OPTARG}
           HELP=0       
        ;;
        r) NGS_R2=${OPTARG}
        #echo "${OPTARG}"
        ;;
        f) FORMAT=${OPTARG}
        ;; 
        h) HELP=1
        #echo "HELP IS $HELP"
        ;;
        s) STEP=${OPTARG}  
        ;;
        v) VERIFICATION=1 
        ;;
        p) REF_PATH=${OPTARG} #reference DB path
        ;;
        m) MODE=${OPTARG} #fast or sensitive
        ;;
        t) THREAD=${OPTARG}
        ;;
        ?) echo "Option -${opt} requires an argument. Please type $0 -h for helps" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
done

if [ $HELP -eq 1 ]
then
    cat <<USAGE

16sPIP version ${Version}

This program will run the 16sPIP pipeline with the supplied parameters.

Command Line Switches:

    -h  Show this help & ignore all other switches

    -i  Specify NGS file or pair-end forward reads for processing

    -r      Specify pair-end reverse reads for processing

    -f  Specify NGS file format (fastq/fasta/bam/sam/sff) [fastq]
        
        16sPIP will support more NGS file formats in the future
        
    -p  Specify the PATH for database (DB)

        16sPIP will search the reference DB under the Path provided.
        
             fast_16S_nucl_DB
             sensitive_nucl_DB

    -v  Verification mode

    -s      jump to that step [1]

    -m      Specify the analysis mode: fast or sensitive [fast]
    -t      number of threads [1]



Usage:

        $0 -i <NGSfile> -f <fastq/fasta/bam/sam/sff> -p <reference_path>

        $0 -i <forward> -r <reverse> -f <fastq> -p <reference_path> -m <fast> -s <step>


USAGE
    exit
fi

if [ ! -f $NGS ]
then
    echo "$NGS file doesnot exist. Please check it"
    exit 65
fi 

if [ $NGS_R2 -a "${FORMAT}" != "fastq" ]
then
        echo "$NGS_R2 must be in fastq format"
    exit 
fi

if [ "$MODE"x != "fast"x -a "$MODE"x != "sensitive"x ]
then
        echo "Specify the analysis mode: fast or sensitive [fast]"
    exit
fi

if [ "${FORMAT}" = "sam" -o "${FORMAT}" = "bam" ]
then
     picard-tools SamToFastq INPUT=$NGS FASTQ=${NGS}.tmp
     mv ${NGS}.tmp $NGS
elif [ "${FORMAT}" = "sff" ]
then
      python ${REF_PATH}/bin/sff_extract $NGS >${NGS}.fastq
      mv ${NGS}.fastq $NGS
fi

if [ "$step" != "" ] 
then 
  goto ${step}
fi

step1:
echo "Step 1: Quality control "
if [ "${FORMAT}" = "fastq" -o "${FORMAT}" = "sam" -o "${FORMAT}" = "bam" -o "${FORMAT}" = "sff" ]
then
    if [ ${NGS_R2} -a -f ${NGS_R2} ]
    then
             /usr/bin/perl ${REF_PATH}/bin/TrimmingReads.pl -i ${NGS} -irev ${NGS_R2} -q 20 -n 50
    else
             /usr/bin/perl ${REF_PATH}/bin/TrimmingReads.pl -i $NGS -q 20 -n 50
    fi
elif [ "${FORMAT}" = "fasta" ]
then
          /usr/bin/perl ${REF_PATH}/bin/TrimmingReads.pl -i $NGS -n 50
else
          echo "Specify NGS file format (fastq/fasta/bam/sam/sff) [fastq]"
      exit
fi

if [ $NGS_R2 -a -f $NGS_R2 ]
then
       goto step2
else
       goto step3
fi

step2:
echo "Step 2: Merge double-ended reads"
${REF_PATH}/bin/pear -f ${NGS}_trimmed -r ${NGS_R2}_trimmed -o $NGS -q 20 -t 50
mv ${NGS}.assembled.fastq ${NGS}_trimmed
rm ${NGS_R2}_trimmed

step3:
echo "Step 3: sequence filtering"
if [ "$FORMAT" = "fasta" ]
then
      perl ${REF_PATH}/bin/FilterReads.pl ${NGS}_trimmed fasta 10
else
      perl ${REF_PATH}/bin/FilterReads.pl ${NGS}_trimmed fastq 10
fi

step4:
echo "Step 4: Results report"
if [ "$FORMAT" = "fasta" ]
then
      python ${REF_PATH}/bin/basicStatistics.py ${NGS}_trimmed_filter fasta ${NGS}.basic_stat.txt
else
      python ${REF_PATH}/bin/basicStatistics.py ${NGS}_trimmed_filter fastq ${NGS}.basic_stat.txt
fi

if [ "$MODE" = "fast" ]
then
      bwa mem -t ${THREAD} ${REF_PATH}/db/155pathogens.fa ${NGS}_trimmed_filter > ${NGS}.sam
      /usr/bin/perl ${REF_PATH}/bin/pathogenSamMatch.pl $NGS.sam ${NGS}.pathon.match.txt
      cat ${NGS}.pathon.match.txt >> ${NGS}.basic_stat.txt
      rm ${NGS}.pathon.match.txt
      /usr/bin/perl ${REF_PATH}/bin/SamSingleResult.pl -i $NGS.sam -s 99 -l species -o $NGS.pathogen
      /usr/bin/perl ${REF_PATH}/bin/PathogenAnnotation.pl -i $NGS.pathogen -l ${REF_PATH}/db/155pathogens.list -o $NGS.pathogen.list
      /usr/bin/perl ${REF_PATH}/bin/FastReport.pl -l $NGS.pathogen.list -s ${NGS}.basic_stat.txt -o ${NGS}.pathogen.prediction.report
elif [ "$MODE" = "sensitive" ]
then
      bwa mem -t ${THREAD} ${REF_PATH}/db/16S-complete.fa ${NGS}_trimmed_filter > $NGS.com.sam &
      echo $! >Job_id
      bwa mem -t ${THREAD} ${REF_PATH}/db/155pathogens.fa ${NGS}_trimmed_filter > $NGS.sam
      /usr/bin/perl ${REF_PATH}/bin/SamSingleResult.pl -i $NGS.sam -l species -s 99 -o $NGS.pathogen
      /usr/bin/perl ${REF_PATH}/bin/PathogenAnnotation.pl -i $NGS.pathogen -l ${REF_PATH}/db/155pathogens.list -o $NGS.pathogen.list
      if [ "$FORMAT" = "fasta" ]
      then
         /usr/bin/perl ${REF_PATH}/bin/extractSequence.pl -i ${NGS}_trimmed_filter -o ${NGS} -l $NGS.pathogen.list -f fasta
      else
         /usr/bin/perl ${REF_PATH}/bin/extractSequence.pl -i ${NGS}_trimmed_filter -o ${NGS} -l $NGS.pathogen.list -f fastq
      fi
      for i in `ls ${NGS}.*.pathon.fa`
      do
       ${REF_PATH}/bin/blastn -query $i -out $i.blast -db ${REF_PATH}/db/16S-complete -outfmt 6 -evalue 1E-20 -num_threads ${THREAD} &
       echo $! >>Job_id
      done
      /usr/bin/perl ${REF_PATH}/bin/pathogenSamMatch.pl $NGS.sam ${NGS}.pathon.match.txt
      cat ${NGS}.pathon.match.txt >> ${NGS}.basic_stat.txt
      while [ 1 ]
      do
       tag=1
       for i in `cat Job_id`
       do
          ID=`ps |grep " $i "`
       if [ "$ID" != "" ]
       then
           tag=0
           sleep 10
       fi
       done
       if [ $tag == 1 ]
       then
            break
       fi
    done
    /usr/bin/perl ${REF_PATH}/bin/SamSingleResult.pl -i $NGS.com.sam -s 99 -l species 
    /usr/bin/perl ${REF_PATH}/bin/SamSingleResult.pl -i $NGS.com.sam -s 97 -l genus
    /usr/bin/perl ${REF_PATH}/bin/SamSingleResult.pl -i $NGS.com.sam -s 95 -l family
    /usr/bin/perl ${REF_PATH}/bin/completeAnnotation.pl $NGS.com.sam.species ${REF_PATH}/db/16S-complete.list species $NGS.com.sam.species.list
    /usr/bin/perl ${REF_PATH}/bin/completeAnnotation.pl $NGS.com.sam.genus ${REF_PATH}/db/16S-complete.list genus $NGS.com.sam.genus.list
    /usr/bin/perl ${REF_PATH}/bin/completeAnnotation.pl $NGS.com.sam.family ${REF_PATH}/db/16S-complete.list family $NGS.com.sam.family.list
    cat ${NGS}.*.pathon.fa.blast >$NGS.tmp.blast
    rm ${NGS}.*.pathon.fa*
    /usr/bin/perl ${REF_PATH}/bin/completeAnnotation.pl $NGS.tmp.blast ${REF_PATH}/db/16S-complete.list species $NGS.tmp.blast.list.species
    /usr/bin/perl ${REF_PATH}/bin/sensitiveReport.pl -l $NGS.pathogen.list -t ${NGS}.basic_stat.txt -g $NGS.com.sam.genus.list -f $NGS.com.sam.family.list -b $NGS.tmp.blast.list.species -s $NGS.com.sam.species.list -o ${NGS}.pathogen.prediction.report
fi

enscript -p ${NGS}.pathogen.prediction.report.ps ${NGS}.pathogen.prediction.report
ps2pdf ${NGS}.pathogen.prediction.report.ps ${NGS}.pathogen.prediction.report.pdf

--------------perl script-----------

#!/usr/bin/perl
# 
#    FilterReads.pl
#    Read filter procedures were based on the read ambiguous base (N) content.
#    
#    FilterReads.pl <seq> <fasta|fastq> <N_percentage> 
#
### Authors : JiaojiaoMiao <jjmiao1314@163.com>


use strict;
use warnings;

if($#ARGV<1){
    die "usage: $0 <seq> <fasta|fastq> <N_percentage>\n";
}

my $f=$ARGV[0];
my $ncutoff;
my $format=$ARGV[1];
if(defined($ARGV[2])){
    $ncutoff=$ARGV[2];
}
else{
    $ncutoff=10;
}

my $o=$f."_filter";
open(F,"<$f")or die "can not open file: $f\n";
open(O,">$o")or die "can not open file: $o\n";

if($format=~/fastq/i){
    while(my $l=<F>){
        my $l2=<F>;
        my $l3=<F>;
        my $l4=<F>;
        my $length=length($l2);
        my $ncount=$l2=~tr/N|n/N/;
        if($length-1 == 0){
            next;
        }
        if($ncount/($length-1)*100<=$ncutoff){
            print O "$l$l2$l3$l4";
        }
    }
}
else{
    my $line=<F>;
    my $ncount=0;
    my $seqlen=0;
    my $seq="";
    while(my $l=<F>){
        if($l=~/^>/){
            if($seqlen != 0){
                if($ncount/$seqlen*100 <=$ncutoff){
                    print O "$line$seq\n";
                }
            }
        $line=$l;
        $ncount=0;
        $seqlen=0;
        $seq="";
        }
        else{
            $l=~s/\s//g;
            $seqlen += length($l);
            $ncount += $l=~tr/N|n/N/;
            $seq .= $l;
        }
    }
    if($seqlen != 0){
        if($ncount/$seqlen*100 <= $ncutoff){
            print O "$line$seq\n";
        }
    }
}

close F;
close O;
-----------------------python script---------------------

#!/usr/bin/python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
#
#

import re,os,sys

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print "usage: basicStatistics.py <parent_file> <fasta|fastq> <outFile>"
    sys.exit(-1)

file=sys.argv[1]
format=sys.argv[2]
outfile=sys.argv[3]

file_size=float(os.path.getsize(file))/1024/1024
#print ("%.3fM\n")%file_size
fh=open(file)
lines=fh.readlines()
if format == "fastq" :
    read=[line[:-1] for line in lines[1::4]]
    reads_num=len(read)
    seq="".join(read).upper()
    base_num=len(seq)
    gc_num=seq.count("C")+seq.count("G")
    gc_num_p=float(gc_num)/base_num*100
elif format == "fasta" :
    read=[line[:-1] for line in lines[1::2]]
    reads_num=len(read)
    seq="".join(read).upper()
    base_num=len(seq)
    gc_num=seq.count("C")+seq.count("G")
    gc_num_p=float(gc_num)/base_num*100
else:
    print "usage: basicStatistics.py <parent_file> <fasta|fastq>"
    sys.exit(-1)

#print ("%s\t%s\n%s\n%s\t%.3f\n")%(read,reads_num,seq,base_num,gc_num_p)

out=open(outfile,'w')
out.write("SampleFile: "+file+"\n")
out.write("Sum Data: %.3fM\n"%file_size)
out.write("Read Num: %i\n"%reads_num)
out.write("Read Len: %i\n"%(base_num/reads_num))
out.write("GC: %.3f\n"%gc_num_p)

fh.close()
out.close()
```

Comment: There are a _lot_ of bad practices in that script. First, you have many unquoted variables which means it will fail on even slightly strange file names (e.g. those containing a space), you have already been told that `goto` isn't a bash thing, and also the `for i in $(cat ...)` [is fragile](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), and the `ps` parsing seems off and not reliable. If you're only using this once, in an academic context, it might be OK if you fix the goto, but if this is something you plan to distribute, I am afraid it isn't fit for purpose.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `goto` command in bash, so the lines in your script that contain this command are incorrect and should be removed.

Also the lines (supposed to be labels, I guess) `step1:`, `step2:`, `step3:` and `step4:` are incorrect and these are the lines actually causing the error messages. On the screenshot you posted, the messages are clear:

```
16sPIP.sh: line 168: step3:: command not found
```

and

```
16sPIP.sh: line 177: step4:: command not found
```

which obviously says that the commands that are "not found" are `step3:` and `step4:`. (You must have had similar messages for `step1:` and `step2:` but they already scrolled off screen and you probably didn't notice them).

Contrary to what you claim, the script does not "crash" with these messages: bash just **ignores** the commands that are not found and continues execution from the next line in the script, which is clearly indicated by the fact that the text `Step 4: Results report` (printed by the `echo` command after `step4:` line in your script) appears on screen and the Python script `basicStatistics.py` begins to execute (but throws a syntax error).

You must redesign your script to get rid of `goto` command and labels, as they don't exist in bash, and replace them with proper control structures.

There's also another problem with your script. The `if` commands containing "bare" `$NGS_R2` variable, like those below, will fail with a syntax error if the variable is empty.

```
if [ $NGS_R2 -a "${FORMAT}" != "fastq" ]
if [ ${NGS_R2} -a -f ${NGS_R2} ]
if [ $NGS_R2 -a -f $NGS_R2 ]
```

I assume you wanted to test that the `$NGS_R2` variable is not empty. In that case you should use the `-n` operator, like this:

```
if [ -n "$NGS_R2" -a "${FORMAT}" != "fastq" ]
if [ -n "${NGS_R2}" -a -f "${NGS_R2}" ]
if [ -n "$NGS_R2" -a -f "$NGS_R2" ]
```

(You also seem to have a syntax error in your Python script `basicStatistics.py` executed in step 4 - an error message is shown on your screenshot - but that's a completely different issue.)

Comment: python3 print is a function, so needs parentheses `(...)` around its arguments.